# How to copy all rows except for the header with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So far, I have everything working with my code except for copying the rows from one sheet to paste at the bottom of the current page. Please see my code below:

```
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Sheet124").Select 'Will be Sheet3 in deployment
Sheets("Sheet124").Name = "Match Exempt"
Sheets("DataInput").Select
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
ActiveSheet.Range("A:AT").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "=Accepting")
ActiveSheet.Range("A:AT").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<9999", _
    Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:AT").AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:="<>Insurance", _
    Operator:=xlAnd
    


  Sheets("Match Exempt").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1). _
    PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Try deleting the row with the headers after pasting.

Comment: I don't see any `Copy` line(s), only pastes ?  It's the Copy you need to adjust (unless you just delete the header after pasting as suggested by Foxfire)

Comment: I left off the copy line I had originally since it was just cells.copy and was grabbing the entire sheet @timWilliams 
How would I go about deleting the header row after pasting since this will be dynamic data and not on the same row everytime I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested above in the comments:

```vb
With Sheets("Match Exempt").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                  SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    .Entirerow.Delete  'remove first row of pasted data
End With
```